# Vuetify <v-file-input> send empty object using axios

Tags: javascript, axios, vuetify.js

I'm facing the same issue as is described [here](https://github.com/api-platform/api-platform/issues/2135) but no one seems to take care of it.

I use Vuetify as my front and I'm trying to create a file upload using `<v-file-input>` but it sends only an empty array.

Here is my Vuetify side code-

```
<v-file-input
  v-model="log_file_upload"
  color="accent"
  counter
  label="File input"
  multiple
  placeholder="Select your files"
  outlined
  :show-size="1000"
  @change="fileUpload"
>
  <template v-slot:selection="{ index, text }">
    <v-chip
      v-if="index < 5"
      color="accent"
      dark
      label
      small
      >
      {{ text }}
    </v-chip>
  </template>
</v-file-input>
```

Here is my JS function-

```
fileUpload: function() {
  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("file", this.log_file_upload[0]);
  axios
    .post(`/upload/`, formData, {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
      }
    })
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data);
    })
},
```

When I console the following result just after `formData.append`-

```
console.log(this.log_file_upload[0].text());
```

I can see the whole file with content but the request sent to the backend is empty. Only the filename is there. Do you guys have any suggestions, please?

Answer (score 0):

There are not many examples that used Vuetify's input to upload the files. However, after reading from a few sources, I came up with this solution-

Remove the `v-model` from input because of two reasons-

1. It will not display the file object's data.
2. Every time we upload, a request is needed to send to the backend, and we already use the `change` event which will pass the file object to its corresponding method, so no need to save the file object anywhere else.

Here is a working example-

**NOTE-** I used a dummy post API to upload the file, and [Axios](https://axios-http.com/docs/intro) to send the API request.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <v-app>
        <v-file-input
          color="accent"
          counter
          label="File input"
          multiple
          placeholder="Select your files"
          outlined
          :show-size="1000"
          @change="fileUpload"
          >
          <template v-slot:selection="{ index, text }">
            <v-chip
              v-if="index < 5"
              color="accent"
              dark
              label
              small
              >
              {{ text }}
            </v-chip>
          </template>
        </v-file-input>
      </v-app>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/1.2.2/axios.min.js" integrity="sha512-QTnb9BQkG4fBYIt9JGvYmxPpd6TBeKp6lsUrtiVQsrJ9sb33Bn9s0wMQO9qVBFbPX3xHRAsBHvXlcsrnJjExjg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <script>
      new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        vuetify: new Vuetify(),
        methods: {
          fileUpload(file) {
            let formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("file", file);
            axios
              .post("https://httpbin.org/post", formData, {
                headers: {
                  "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
                },
              })
              .then((res) => {
                console.log(res);
              });
          },
        },
      })
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment but it does not solve the problem. Besides remove of v-model I do not see any major change and issue still persists. Problem is the content of the file is not send to backend. If you try for example some csv file.